# swift - CoreData from prepopulated SQLite

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, swift

I've populated a database with CoreData and now I want to use it as the default database in my app in swift.
I've read about it but I only found tutorials in Objective-C and the methods of Core Data that Xcode6 creates in the AppDelegate are kindly strange for me...

This is the code:

```
    // MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "RLopez.BORRAME" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
    }()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("iManager", withExtension: "momd")
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)
    }()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("iManager.sqlite")
    println(url)
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError.errorWithDomain("YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
    }()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
    }()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is to use a sqlite file I have in my app bundle instead of creating an empty database.
How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copy sqlite file from app bundle to the place where persistent store is.

Here's my code:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("db.sqlite")

   //this part
    if (!NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(url.path!)) {
        let defaultStorePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("db", ofType:"sqlite")

        NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(defaultStorePath!, toPath:url.path!, error: nil)
    }

    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: nil) == nil {
        coordinator = nil
    }
    return coordinator
    }()
```

Comment: A quick question: when you have saved to core data, how do you retrieve it? I know how to retrieve when using "regular" core data, but then I have defined everything in my NSManagedObject-class. Do I have to define the database in my NSManagedObject-class or in my xcdatamodel in some way?

Comment: This throws an error: Extra argument 'error' in call

Comment: @GeorgeAsda ok I will.

Comment: @Yaroslav i just did it for you

Answer (score 3):

This is the proper way for SWIFT2:

```
 lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
        var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("db.sqlite")

        //this part
        if (!NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(url.path!)) {
            let defaultStorePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("db", ofType:"sqlite")

            do {
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(defaultStorePath!, toPath:url.path!)
            } catch _ {
            }
        }

        do {
            try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
        } catch _ {
            coordinator = nil
        }
        return coordinator
        }()
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = Globals.userDocumentsURL.appendingPathComponent("db.sqlite")


    //this part
    if (!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path)) {
        let defaultStorePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "db", ofType:"sqlite")

        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(atPath: defaultStorePath!, toPath:url.path)
        } catch _ {
        }
    }

    do {
        try coordinator!.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
    } catch _ {
        coordinator = nil
    }
    return coordinator
}()
```