# Swift - Populate core data from premade sqlite file

Tags: swift, core-data

Not the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477426/swift-coredata-from-prepopulated-sqlite).

I have a premade sqlite file that has three columns: chapter, verseNumber and verseText. My core data entity has the same name for its attributes. How do I populate the core data database from my sqlite file?

Comment: How did you pre-build the sqlite file? Is it a Core Data file?

Comment: I'm using [SQLiteBrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/). It is not a Core Data file. I need to make it a Core Data file.

Comment: Checkout the FMDB project. You can use it to parse and iterate through the data in the sqlite file and then persist it into Core Data http://stackoverflow.com/a/17268032/413570

Comment: @rodrigoalves Can I then delete the sqlite file and just use the Core Data file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
@IBAction func getSQLDB (sender: NSButton) {

    let documentsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let path = documentsFolder.stringByAppendingPathComponent("kjv.db")

    println(documentsFolder)

    let database = FMDatabase(path: path)

    if !database.open() {
        println("Unable to open database")
        return
    }

    //if let rs = database.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM bible WHERE (book = 'Gen') AND (chapter = '1')", withArgumentsInArray: nil) {
    if let rs = database.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM bible WHERE (book = 'Genesis') OR (book = 'Exodus')", withArgumentsInArray: nil) {
        while rs.next() {
            let content = rs.stringForColumn("content")
            let verseNumber: Int! = rs.stringForColumn("verse").toInt()
            let chapter: Int! = rs.stringForColumn("chapter").toInt()
            let name = rs.stringForColumn("book")
            // Loops through all the information from the query and creates a book
            makeBook(name, content: content, chapter: chapter, verseNumber: verseNumber)
        }
    } else {
        println("select failed: \(database.lastErrorMessage())")
    }

    database.close()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Core Data can not read arbitrary SQLite files. You would have to convert the file into a Core Data database manually. The format that Core Data uses to read from / write to SQLite is proprietary.

You have to use SQLite directly to read the data. I'd suggest using something like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) for reading the data. To put the data into a Core Data store, you should follow the guidelines of [Efficiently Importing Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html).

Comment: Right. How do I do that?