# How to populate a CoreData store with data

Tags: xcode, core-data

I'm looking for a way to populate my CoreData store with data. Is there a simple way to import data (for example entity: animal, attributes: name, color, size) into the App's CoreData "database"?

This would be data already there when distributing the App. No need for importing / converting JSON / CSV / XML or similar, just a plain import (I've written a load JSON and convert into CoreData routine, but I'm sure this can be done easier and not being part of the App, it doesn't have to be). I guess similar to importing into Excel, MS Acces, ... I would expect an Xcode import data function.

I hope I explained myself clearly, this is my first question you know... :-)

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: The *plainest* text format is CSV. In any case you have to write the import logic. And *not being part of the App* implies that the data is loaded from a server. There is no effortless way.

Comment: You can provide a variable that contains an array of the data you want your app to start with, then on first run, iterate that array and populate your database.

Comment: A -1 on my first question, that hurts. Anyway, thanks for the clarification, I'll stick with the import routine.

Comment: If your conversion routine produces a CoreData SQLite file, you can add that to your Xcode project and include it in the app bundle.  Then you need a routine in your app to copy it from the app bundle - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25477426/3985749) for example.

Comment: Back to 0, that feels better, Thanks for the link!